# Lock Android APP to specific device

Tags: android, security

Is it possible to lock an Android APP to only work with a specific device (as in one phone with an specific id/imei/token) and prevent anyone from taking the app and using it in any other device?

Would it be possible to hardcode a device token in the code (or store it encrypted) and check that it matches the one it's being currently ran on and close (or show an error) if they are not the same? Could an Android Device Token even be used for this? Is it linked to hardware (an unique device will always have the same token, even after flashing a ROM)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would work.

You need to call `android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId();`

This will return whatever string uniquely identifies the device (IMEI on GSM, MEID for CDMA).

You'll need the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

in order to do this.

Then, you can check if the IMEI matches the target device in your MainActivity's `onCreate()` and if it doesn't, call `finish();`

You can encrypt the target's IMEI using Facebook's "Conceal" library, for example.

Comment: Any way the user could bypass it in any way? Could the deviceId be altered? I guess even if it could they would have to know the exact deviceId that would make the app work...

Comment: The user would need to be fairly sophisticated. On "rooted" phones, the IMEI can be changed by the user. The app can be reverse-engineered to extract the deviceId for which the app is allowed to run. But as I said, the user would have to know how to reverse-engineer APKs, so the check would definitely prevent a "regular" user from using the app illegitimately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do it ,but we have to handle this thing as in below process:
1) We can get android id or imei of device by this code:

```
String imei;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            if(isSimSupport(mContext))
            {
                imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            }
            if(imei.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                imei= Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            }
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                String userId=preference.getUserId("UserId");
                String devicetoken=preference.getToken("token");
                sendRegistrationToServer(imei,userId,devicetoken);
            } else {
                toastMsg(getResources().getString(R.string.internet_alert));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Check this imei value when start the app if it matches then do exitfrom
app code:

```
protected void exitFromApp() {
        finish();
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        localIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
        localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(localIntent);
    }

public static boolean isSimSupport(Context context)
    {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return !(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT);
    }
```

for normal users point of view it seems that it is not working on that device.
It is a trick but there is no code to block the app running or installation.